# Canel search on press close Button

Tags: search, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing a search dialog with Cancel button.
When the user starts searching, the result will get populated
in the TableViewer from the DB, one by one, along with the progress displayed
in a progress bar.

Suppose the user wants to cancel the search, he will click the Cancel button.

How to stop the data populating process??

```
SearchProgressBar dlg=new  SearchProgressBar(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell());
dlg.open();
for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
String str=FillGistTable(result[i].toString().split("\\~"),i);
COUNT++;
}
dlg.close()
```

Comment: Use IProgressMonitor.isCanceled() method.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using `IProgressService`

```
IProgressService service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService();
service.busyCursorWhile(runnableWithProgress);
```

`runnableWithProgess` is a class implementing `IRunnableWithProgress` which is where you put your loop. You will be passed an `IProgressMonitor` - check the `isCanceled()` method to check for cancel.

If your loop complete quickly no dialog is shown, but if it takes longer a progress dialog with cancel is displayed.

Note: `IProgressService` is not available in a pure 'e4' Eclipse 4 application.